# Stop programs from starting with Windows when it wakes up from sleep

Tags: windows-7, windows, sleep, wake-up

I know that `MSConfig` is used to check and prevent programs from starting up (from boot), as explained in the answers to [this](https://superuser.com/q/13150/81403) question, but I want to know how to check the programs that open when my computer **wakes from sleep**.

Specifically, every time my computer wakes up, *Norton Internet Security* asks me if I'd like to upgrade....

What program or utility can help me with this?

Comment: Just to make sure I get it right, you mean wakeup from standby / sleep mode?
If so, the operating system just restores the previous session, speaking only the programs that ran before are restored.
Or am I not getting the question?

Comment: *terms:* not **starting**, but **resuming**

Comment: Norton Internet Security is asking you to upgrade to what? It is the "ultimate" security product they have and it should not ask you to upgrade it. Are you sure you have Internet Security installed and not another product?

Comment: Not really an answer to your question (hence why it's a comment) but have you considered/ are you able to consider another antivirus program? I've had nothing but problems with Norton over the years and their constant whinging about upgrading wasn't helping my attitude toward them. There is a list of antivirus partners here: http://www.microsoft.com/windows/antivirus-partners/windows-7.aspx I use AVG at home, Work uses Eset, I have tried Avast and a lot of people like it but it's not for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get free Winpatrol from same domain. Its free and allows you to disable and then kill if app is active (prompt option). It also allows you to configure Scheduled tasks, services, startups (disable or delete), tracks changes in associations and much more.  Very low resource and CPU bandwidth used. No reboot needed to activate changes. It is very good. Another is Mike Lin's startup mgr.
I recommend you uninstall Norton and stick with MS Antimalware with Winpatrol and use a sandboxed browser like Chrome Opera or IE9 and use a browser addon such as WOT (Web of trust, & No script ) for additional security consideration.

I consider a well tuned PC with minimal but adequate security one to boot with < 20 **processes** shown in same tab of taskmgr in XP after boot. 25 for Vista and 30 for Win7.

Alo Check > Computer> Manage> Scheduled Tasks> Microsoft > and look for execute on startup ...according to the huge list of categories listed ....

Comment: thanks, who can you trust these days? no one. not even MS Antimalware,, all gone from my system, still good. Mike Lin's simple program gives instant alert based on waiting for OS to detect key changes in reg in designated areas and alert rather than scanning like everyone else.  Even Windows scan/detect update process tasks  a big burden at unexpected times.  Unfortunately all AV suites still behave like trojans that make PC's sluggish to me.  Try safe mode and compare web response or whatever!

Comment: that's why i started to use foss-software and finally switched to linux-based systems years ago: no thoughts about bloated av-suites, and nearly none about malware. **;-)** -- and additional i don't have to buy a new pc after nearly every release and learn a new gui although i don't want to.

Comment: That's why I set up Win8 to look like Win7 and my hex core i7 will suit my needs until it dies and disable all updates for better stability/speed and more than adequate immunity. Although MINT Is nice, I have way more tools on Win. but then the best tools are the one you how to use and save time.

Comment: 1) why buying something and then have to "fix" it before using...? -- 2) disabling updates never sounds like a good idea! -- 3) yes, i'm using linux mint gnome2/mate since 2008. **;-)** - i simply invested once the time instead for installing and fixing a new windows into migrating and thats it. granted, it was easy because i already used some (platform independent) foss-software on windows... but thats definitely off-topic now...

Comment: Disabling Startup Apps in windows is key to getting at least 3x the performance for free, by careful Engineering off the Scheduled tasks, Services and Apps. with several tools. A PITA, but worth it. It always amazes me how many Deferred Procedure Calls (DPC) are incurred each second of idle. I have beeen manually disabling Win Updates and comparing performance with other PC's with updates since WinXP and satisfied with my decisions.

Comment: well... i know the complexity/problems of setting up windows, but among others all this i spare myself! **;-)** -- maybe this is worth a look for you: http://www.wsusoffline.net/ - it is not just an offline-update, you also get more control of the whole process and it leaves out the unwanted garbage!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting your problem right, there isn't any special registry entry for all programs.
Mostly I think when it comes to *Norton IS* it simply checks the last time it displayed this dialog and after your PC slept, this dialog is triggered because it has been to long.

Comment: *Norton IS* displays the dialog **every** time I wake up my PC.  It doesn't matter if its been one minute or twenty.