# How can I stop a software from recurring in startup?

Tags: windows-xp, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stop programs from starting up automaticly on boot on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/13150/stop-programs-from-starting-up-automaticly-on-boot-on-windows)

I installed a software which start up with windows. I tried to disable it with CCleaner, however, it shows up at start up again ( maybe it configure to set the registry to true everytime it runs).

How can I disable it in startup permanently?

Comment: @Mokubai: This is not really a duplicate. The OP states he has tried to disable the offending program with CCleaner but it keeps returning. The question here is how to stop the program from re-enabling itself *after* it has been disabled.

Comment: That question also gives some other methods of disabling autorun programs so is worth a look at the very least. If the program itself is re-enabling the run at startup then that is a problem with the program itself and as we have no idea what the program is we currently cannot help besides telling him to look in the options for that program.

Answer (score 3):

Look at a program called [auto-runs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx). It might take a while to find the name of the program that you are looking for (it shows you every possible place that it could be, which is good in that you know everything is there, but bad in that it can be hard to find things).

As a suggestion, there is more than one part to this program, and CCleaner only found one part.

For a simpler view of what is starting up, user `msconfig` and see the startup and services tab.

Answer (score 2):

There are several places I know to look for programs that run automatically:

- The startup folder in your start menu. Don't forget to check both your own folder and the All Users folder.
- Three different places in the registry:

  - `HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Run` (plus RunOnce,RunServices,etc)
  - `HKCU/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Run` (plus RunOnce,RunServices,etc)
  - `HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows NT/CurrenVersion/WinLogon` Look at the shell and userinit keys. The normal values are explorer.exe and userinit.exe, but you can list more than one item here or change them to items that replace the shell or another program that starts the normal shell when it loads.
- Services. Hit the Windows key and type "services.msc". Look for services set to start automatically, automatically (delayed), or at user login.
- Scheduled Tasks. Look for tasks set to run at user login.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely the program is running in the background and is automatically re-enabling itself every time you disable it. Try closing the program completely, or preferably kill the process, and afterwards, disable the startup entry.

You may want to use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to help you find the name of the process quickly. Then look for the name of the program in the list of startup entries in [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) and disable/delete the relevant entry.

Comment: If a program is doing this, the risk that it installed a key-logging rootkit, in addition to anything else you might find, is great enough that it's time to change passwords and reinstall your system. You might easily remove one part of the threat, but miss the more subtle danger. There's rarely just one bug anymore. The first infection will bring others along for the ride.