# How do I manage what programs startup in Windows 8?

Tags: boot, windows-8

There's a nifty new tab in the 'Task Manager' called 'Startup' where I can manage the program that run at startup.

[image]

BUT... It doesn't show all of the application that run at startup:

[image]

Some of the hidden culprits are:

- Steam
- Skype
- Google Drive
- Dropbox
- Cisco VPN
- Java Update

"What about the registry?" Here's what's found in there:

[image]

Which doesn't contain all of the running programs.

How do I manage these startup applications from within Windows 8?

Comment: Keywords "from within Windows 8" meaning using Windows itself and not the application's settings, right?

Comment: @Louis that's correct... I don't want to have to go into each application and manually make the changes... plus some (cough cough SKYPE) don't even obey my command to not run at startup.

Comment: I wonder if they're getting autostarted by some other means. Maybe under services?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek They are probably in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`, but I don't know of a Windows tool, besides Regedit, that let's you change those.

Comment: @Louis I'd be really sad if I have to resort to using regedit

Comment: Just to note that msconfig *does* not work here.

Comment: @KronoS check out this [article](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/where-is-startup-folder-how-to-edit-startup-items-in-windows-8/) where `dropbox` is showing up in startup manager.

Comment: @KronoS see also: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop programs from starting up automatically on boot on Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/13150/stop-programs-from-starting-up-automatically-on-boot-on-windows)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 This isn't quite a dupe of the linked question.  All of the solutions on the 'dupe' are items I've already addressed in the question (since both msconfig is the same as the startup tab above, and the startup folder no longer exists in the start menu).

Comment: I'm surprised I have to say this to a 15K+ user (maybe you didn't have it back in 2012 ;) ) -- If you'd like newer/updated answers to the existing question, place a bounty on it.  As for the answers there, one of them specifically suggests Autoruns, which is what you accepted as "the answer" here.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: This is not a duplicate. The linked question is for Windows XP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a list of all software that starts automatically when Windows 7 starts?](http://superuser.com/questions/507194/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-software-that-starts-automatically-when-windows-7-start)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(This tool is not built in Window 8 but...) You can use [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) from Windows Sysinternals to figure out what applications are starting up on startup. You can also disable them too.

Comment: +1. Probably no other app knows all the possible startup locations like this one does (no surprises, since it's from MS).

Answer (score 2):

There is always Registry Editor (regedit.exe).

Apps that launch on startup are located in:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` and

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

You would stop an item from launching by deleting its key.

[image]

It's up to you if you want to save them or not (i.e., just by jotting down the strings, and the key type), in case you want to readd them later.

There's also this key location as well: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\MSConfig`  Which yields the following:

[image]

Deleting the entire folder should stop if from running at startup.

Of course this is not an elegant way to manage things. I would only use it if the application didn't respect its own settings.

Comment: I would like a more elegant solution, and this also doesn't cover all of the application either.

Comment: @KronoS I would too, hope there's a better answer.

Comment: I updated your answer to reflect where I found the keys.  Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely nothing better than [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) for this, [now with added Win8 supprt](http://www.ghacks.net/2012/06/25/ccleaner-3-20-update-brings-windows-8-support-context-menu-editor/). Look under Tools -> Startup:

[image]

To remove an entry simply right click on it and select "Delete":

[image]

And then select Ok:

[image]

Note: You might need to run CCleaner as admin to remove these entries.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my specific case, using CCleaner doesn't work (no matter if I use as admin or not).  But this may be due to a hard drive failing as well as my system is acting up now.  Will test on a more stable system and see if this does work there.

Comment: CCleaner is awful. Just saying...

Comment: Go on then, elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that `msconfig.exe` still works in Windows-8 too. You can manage your startup items there. You can also can use [free version of CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/builds) and a very good application named [soluto](https://www.soluto.com/#) which can measure the booting time and let you know which program you can disable to decrease the boot time.

[How to geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/64548/soluto-solves-pc-crashes-and-speeds-up-boot-time.-download-it-now/) has an article about soluto which covers on how to use it.

Comment: msconfig just throws you back to task manager.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek  I didn't know about that. Thanks for mention.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend against editing the registry directly.

There is a nice tool by sysinternals called autoruns:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

[image: screenshot of autoruns]

It finds all possible places for an application to startup (including services) and presents in an easy way to turn them off (**and back on again if you notice system issues**)