# How can I stop a PowerShell script from running?

Tags: windows, script, powershell

I have (so far unsuccessfully) tried to install SharePoint on my Windows 7/8.1 laptop.

It fails when installing a particular prerequisite (Windows Identification something-or-other).

But that's not my question, that's just a lead-up.

Every time I boot up my laptop since the failed install, a PowerShell script runs, re-trying the prereq install. I want to prevent that. I don't want the script to run any more. What must I do to send PowerShell a "cease and desist" directive regarding this particular operation?

Comment: Do you know what script is trying to run?

Comment: No, but you can see it here in Update 4: [link](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/132002/how-can-i-get-share-point-2010-to-install-on-my-windows-7-8-1-machine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering that this PowerShell script (usually with extension `*.ps1`) runs during the boot phase, I would have a look at the programs/services that have to be loaded at the startup and disable the execution of such script.

This could be done using `msconfig` (running it through `WINDOWS + R`) or using programs like [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) that allow to see and select/unselect the programs/service to load at the startup.

See this other SU question for more information/alternatives: [How to get a list of all software that starts automatically when Windows 7 starts?](https://superuser.com/questions/507194/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-software-that-starts-automatically-when-windows-7-start)