# What to do when "msconfig" cannot stop an app from starting?

Tags: windows-7, windows, vpn, boot, msconfig

I'm using Windows 7, 64 bit, I'm having an issue with [Private Tunnel](https://www.privatetunnel.com/), it's a VPN application. It keeps starting when Windows start, even though it's not supposed to.

These are the only apps that are supposed to start

[image]

Private tunnel is unchecked in `msconfig`. *(And of course I restarted windows, if you're asking)*

[image]

Private Tunnel itself, does not have an option to prevent the app from starting, as far as I know. I contacted the support team 2 weeks ago, they didn't comment on the issue. Every time I start the computer, I have to right click on the icon and exit.

So my question is, what to do when `msconfig` cannot stop an app from starting?

Comment: Check your `Startup` folder.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/13150/stop-programs-from-starting-up-automaticly-on-boot-on-windows?rq=1

Comment: Check the general tab and make sure it is on selective startup. Then also check your services tab. There might be a service in there that is to do with Private Tunnel that is set to start. Change this to manual and try restarting again. Good luck!

Comment: @sawdust I just checked the ``folder` it's `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` as far as i know and it is empty, no hidden folders, I guess i'm gonna contact the support team again and have them look at this topic

Comment: @RichardPowell I'm using the selective startup which you can tell by looking at the second photo, dropbox is unchecked and it doesn't start, therefore you can tell  that indeed i'm using it, I rechecked to make sure, and there's no service for openvpn, all the services are for microsoft and hp

Comment: @golimar the accepted answer doesn't help obviously, I'm gonna have to try the other answers, although i'm not feeling good about downloading third party software to mess with my startup, and i think they won't be any better than `msconfig`

Comment: I ask whether there could be a scheduled task (or a startup script) that opened the program regrardless of startup configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use other software that does the trick.

[HijackThis](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hjt/) and [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-en/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) both work just like msconfig. They list the programs that start up and allow you to select those that should have their autostart entries removed.

HijackThis is a bit rudimentary, but will work great for most problems. Autoruns is supplied by Microsoft and supports all possible ways of autostarting programs. Chances are that the program you try to deactivate uses methods that aren't supported by msconfig. Give those two tools a shot and you should be set.

Answer (score 3):

Although I don't have Private tunnel installed, I am guessing it creates a service(also accessible from msconfig). Uncheck that and restart again.
Still didn't work?
get ccleaner and do this: click tools>startup and delete the entry completely
you'll also see a scheduled tasks tab just above the list. disable it from there also. 
(this is just a guess, I don't have private tunnel installed so i'm not sure)

Comment: Why are you only guessing how the software works?  This answer isn't all that helpful.  CCLeaner only provides a graphical interface to the exact same startup information that msconfig does.

Comment: Actually the answer is useful, in the sense he refers to Services (that can be checked in Administrator Tools), and they can only be disabled in there.