# Stop adding unwanted processes to autorun after program update

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, autorun, chocolatey

### 1. Summary

I install program → [**I remove program/service of program from autorun**](https://superuser.com/q/13150/572069) → I update program → program/service in autorun again.

How I can remove process from Windows autorun preventively, even if program update?

---

### 2. Details

I upgrade 100+ my programs via Chocolatey — [**`choco upgrade all`**](https://chocolatey.org/docs/commandsupgrade).

**Examples**: Adobe Flash Player, Chrome, Docker and Skype update for me:

[image: Updated programs]

I uncheck this services in [**Autoruns**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) → services doesn't run in Windows reboot.

`choco upgrade all` again → **if** Adobe Flash Player/Chrome/Docker/Skype update, services above again in autorun.

---

### 3. Not helped

1. [**msconfig**](https://superuser.com/a/13155/572069),
2. [**Autoruns**](https://superuser.com/a/13426/572069).

---

### 4. Do not offer

Please, do not offer, that I shouldn't use and/or update Chrome, Docker and another programs. I need to use the newest versions of these programs, but I don't want unwanted processes in autorun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a choco package (or just a simple batch file) which you will launch after choco upgrade which will simply launch **.reg** file [crafted to remove autorun keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334207/regedit-file-format) you need. This way you can also update or add some Registry keys or do other things (e.g. in file system) so later you might find more universal use for this post-deployment step.

Comment: [**Example for my programs with comments**](https://github.com/Kristinita/SashaTwickenham/blob/master/SashaRemoveUnexpectedProcesses.reg). That disable warning window, when change registry, use [**another tweak**](https://github.com/Kristinita/SashaTwickenham/blob/master/SashaDisableRegeditWarning.reg). Thanks.